# Unity build to iOS errors

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xcode, google-api

I made a game in unity that works perfectly on android but when i build it to iOS I get the following errors in Xcode:

""_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMOAuth2Authentication"

Is there a file i have to download? I looked for it on the net but i couldn't find it.

I also get this message after the build:

3. Add the '-ObjC' linker flag. To do this, select the top-level project
   object, select the 'Unity-iPhone' build target, then go to the
   Build Settings tab. Search for Other Linker Flags and add
   the '-ObjC' flag to that list.

** Note: To run in the simulator, use Unity 4.6.8 or greater.

Do I have to find this online and download it?

How can fix the above error?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. If anyone else is having this problem,and not using cocoapods, you have to import these frameworks as well:

```
GoogleAppUtilities.framework
GoogleAuthUtilities.framework
GoogleNetworkingUtilities.framework
GoogleSignIn.framework
GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework
GoogleUtilities.framework
```

Then if an error saying"inflate" or "deflate" comes up, you have to

- Go to the project Build Settings tab
- Search for Other Linker Flags
- Add -lz as a linker flag
- In the Product menu, select Clean before building again